# Ошибка в работе со стеком LUA из C++

Tags: c++, lua

Приветствую. Работаю со скриптом `LUA` и C++. Суть проблемы в том, что данные из `Lua` скрипта не попадают в стек, или С++ неверно со стеком работает. Подробнее, вот скрипт работающий на `LUA` машине :

```
require("QluaConnector");
is_run=true;

function main()
while is_run == true do
for i = 1, 3, 1 do

-- print(tostring(i));   -- такой вывод на экран срабатывает верно
QluaConnector.StartSendData(i);  -- а этот уже нет
sleep(1000);
end;
end
end;
```

Единственное что мне нужно так это последовательно передавать в стек и читать из него три цифры : 1, 2, 3.

Код на С++ :

```
static int forLua_StartDataGet(lua_State *L) 
{
while (true)
    {
    int value = lua_tonumber(L, 1);
    lua_pop(L,-1);
    Sleep(1000);
    return(value );
    }
}
```

В первый раз метод действительно возвращает 1, однако вместо 2 и 3 уже ноль. Если вместо `lua_tonumber` посмотреть число элементов в стеке `lua_gettop` то в 1 раз функция вернет 1 а во второй и дальнейшие по 0. Подозреваю, что ошибка или в скрипте или в С++, помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `return` нужно возвращать не значение, а число значений, возвращаемых функцией. В `Lua` функция может вернуть несколько значений. Само же возвращаемое значение, предварительно заносится в стек. Ну и `lua_pop` тут вообще не нужен.

```
static int forLua_StartDataGet(lua_State *L) 
{
    int value = lua_tonumber(L, 1);
    lua_pushinteger(L, value); // положить результат в стек
    return 1; // говорим lua, что вернули одно значение на стеке   
}
```

---

Если функция не должна ничего возвращать, то код становится ещё проще:

```
static int forLua_StartDataGet(lua_State *L) 
{
    int value = lua_tonumber(L, 1);

    ... // используем value

    return 0; // говорим lua, что наша функция ничего не возвращает
}
```

Comment: C++ не должен возвращать значение в lua а только принимать 3 разных числа, чего он не делает независимо от того нужно ли что то возвращать.

Comment: @Сергей Ну, я же не знаю, что ваша функция должна делать. Если вам не надо ничего возвращать, то уберите `lua_pushinteger` и сделайте `return 0;`. Делов-то!

Comment: @Сергей И почитайте хотя бы вот [этот туториал](http://ilovelua.narod.ru/step3.html), а то создаётся впечатление, что вы совсем не понимаете что там и как происходит.

Comment: Так изначально у меня и не было кода кроме `lua_tonumber` который выбирал 1 элемент в стеке но при повторном вызове ф-и с++, скрипт должен поместить туда совсем другой элемент и функция должна получить 2 но никак не 0.

Comment: за мануал спасибо. именно этого не читал

Comment: @Сергей Вы портили стек вызовом `lua_pop` + говорили lua, что возвращаете некоторое число значений, чего на самом деле не делали. А это ломало стек ещё раз.

Comment: Проблема оказалась совсем в другом месте (неожиданно) а как только попробовал вывести в файл данные из скрипта - все получилось как надо. А на счет того что портил `lua_pop ` не соглашусь - http://ilovelua.narod.ru/step4.html

Comment: @Сергей Я бы сказал, что проблема была **и** в другом месте. Это да, вполне может быть. А `lua_pop` нужно использовать лишь там, где это нужно. И это не случай из кода в вопросе, согласны в с этим или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Функция `lua_pop` принимает на вход количество элементов, которые надо убрать со стека. Соответственно это число должно быть положительным.

```
lua_pop(L, 1);
```

Comment: К сожалению это не решило проблемы. Я получаю вначале `1` как положено но затем `0.00`.

Comment: Если же попробую получить последний элемент в стеке `value = lua_tonumber(L, -1)` то иногда проскакивает 3. но потом снова по нулям